# Replace DataFrame rows with most recent data based on key

Tags: date, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
user_id      val        date
1            10         2015-02-01
1            11         2015-01-01
2            12         2015-03-01
2            13         2015-02-01
3            14         2015-03-01
3            15         2015-04-01
```

I need to run a function that calculates (let's say) the sum of vals chronologically by the dates. If a user has a more recent date, use that date, but if not, keep the older date.

For example. If I run the function with the date 2015-03-15, then the table will be:

```
user_id      val        date
1            10         2015-02-01
2            12         2015-03-01
3            14         2015-03-01
```

Giving me a sum of 36.

If I run the function with the date 2015-04-15, then the table will be:

```
user_id      val        date
1            10         2015-02-01
2            12         2015-03-01
3            15         2015-04-01
```

(User 3's row was replaced with a more recent date).

I know this is fairly esoteric, but thought I could bounce this off all of you as I have been trying to think of a simple way of doing this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
In [36]: df.loc[df.date <= '2015-03-15']
Out[36]:
   user_id  val       date
0        1   10 2015-02-01
1        1   11 2015-01-01
2        2   12 2015-03-01
3        2   13 2015-02-01
4        3   14 2015-03-01

In [39]: df.loc[df.date <= '2015-03-15'].sort_values('date').groupby('user_id').agg({'date':'last', 'val':'last'}).reset_index()
Out[39]:
   user_id       date  val
0        1 2015-02-01   10
1        2 2015-03-01   12
2        3 2015-03-01   14
```

or:

```
In [40]: df.loc[df.date <= '2015-03-15'].sort_values('date').groupby('user_id').last().reset_index()
Out[40]:
   user_id  val       date
0        1   10 2015-02-01
1        2   12 2015-03-01
2        3   14 2015-03-01

In [41]: df.loc[df.date <= '2015-04-15'].sort_values('date').groupby('user_id').last().reset_index()
Out[41]:
   user_id  val       date
0        1   10 2015-02-01
1        2   12 2015-03-01
2        3   15 2015-04-01
```